# Setting phone to silence, but play notification sound on incoming mail from certain contact

Tags: notifications, audio

I know "blocking mode" on Samsung S3, but it allows only phone calls from certain contacts. Can I do the same for email sound notifications for certain contacts? preferably without installing any apps...